# return the object on GET request Exception filters

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to return object with json data through a ASP.NET WEb API call.
I want to return the data in the form `IHttpActionResult`

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "statuscode": "SuccessCode",
  "statusmessage": "SuccessMsg",
  "data": [
    {
      "corrBD1": null,
      "flagType1": null,
      "status1": null,
      "mstrRep1": null,
      "repname1": null,
      "nameAccount1": null,
      "acDate1": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "preAddress1": null,
      "currAddress1": null
    }]
}
```

I can return this data on a valid GET request as:

```
return OK(employee);
```

but when there is an exception occurs i need to return the data in the same form

```
    {
  "message": "fail",
  "statuscode": "400",
  "statusmessage": "failmsg",
  "data": null
}
```

but the exception filters forcing me to send the respond in the form of `HttpResponseMessage` (which unfortunately not able to return in required form)
how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are simply trying to use your consistent message syntax in the result regardless of whether you are handling the response in the controller or the exception filter. You should be able to do what you want by creating your own IHttpActionResult:

```
private class MyResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
               new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); // or whatever
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content); // your content here
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

In your handler you just set `ExceptionHandlerContext.Request` to the instance you created above. Does that work for your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeremy !! I have implemented your solution. I have done some changes in it and able to implement the desired result.
 please check the code and give suggestions.

```
   public class CustomExceptionResult : IHttpActionResult
        {
            private HttpRequestMessage _request;
            private HttpResponseMessage _httpResponseMessage;


            public CustomExceptionResult(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage, Employee data)
            {
                _request = request;                

                _httpResponseMessage = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, data);

            }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(_httpResponseMessage);
            }
        }
```

This is my exception handler code.

```
    public class NotFoundExceptionFilter:ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Exception is KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                var msg = context.Exception.Message;
//class for creating standard Json object
                JsonWrapper data= new JsonWrapper("There is some problem with the key you are looking for","400","Bad Request",null);
                Controllers.NotFoundExceptionResult result = new Controllers.NotFoundExceptionResult(context.Request, data);
                context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);                
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnException(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the below Json in Result:

```
{
  "message": "There is some problem with the key you are looking for",
  "statuscode": "400",
  "statusmessage": "Bad request",
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: It looks like you were able to do what you needed with the NotFoundExceptionResult, so not sure you need the Custom one (unless that's what you are using to create the latter).